# Advent of code 2023 day 7: Ranking Camel Cards hands - mostly in Bash

Tags: programming-challenge, bash

#### Part 1

[Today's task](https://adventofcode.com/2023/day/7) is to rank hands in a Camel Cards game and compute the total score.

> In Camel Cards, you get a list of hands, and your goal is to order
> them based on the strength of each hand. A hand consists of five cards
> labeled one of A, K, Q, J, T, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, or 2. The relative
> strength of each card follows this order, where A is the highest and 2
> is the lowest.
>
> Every hand is exactly one type. From strongest to weakest, they are:
>
> - Five of a kind, where all five cards have the same label: AAAAA
> - Four of a kind, where four cards have the same label and one card has a different label: AA8AA
> - Full house, where three cards have the same label, and the remaining two cards share a different label: 23332
> - Three of a kind, where three cards have the same label, and the remaining two cards are each different from any other card in the
>   hand: TTT98
> - Two pair, where two cards share one label, two other cards share a second label, and the remaining card has a third label: 23432
> - One pair, where two cards share one label, and the other three cards have a different label from the pair and each other: A23A4
> - High card, where all cards' labels are distinct: 23456
>
> Hands are primarily ordered based on type; for example, every full
> house is stronger than any three of a kind.
>
> If two hands have the same type, a second ordering rule takes effect.
> Start by comparing the first card in each hand. If these cards are
> different, the hand with the stronger first card is considered
> stronger. If the first card in each hand have the same label, however,
> then move on to considering the second card in each hand. If they
> differ, the hand with the higher second card wins; otherwise, continue
> with the third card in each hand, then the fourth, then the fifth.
>
> So, 33332 and 2AAAA are both four of a kind hands, but 33332 is
> stronger because its first card is stronger. Similarly, 77888 and
> 77788 are both a full house, but 77888 is stronger because its third
> card is stronger (and both hands have the same first and second card).
>
> To play Camel Cards, you are given a list of hands and their
> corresponding bid (your puzzle input). For example:
>
> > ```
> > 32T3K 765
> > T55J5 684
> > KK677 28
> > KTJJT 220
> > QQQJA 483
> > ```
>
> This example shows five hands; each hand is followed by its bid
> amount. Each hand wins an amount equal to its bid multiplied by its
> rank, where the weakest hand gets rank 1, the second-weakest hand gets
> rank 2, and so on up to the strongest hand. Because there are five
> hands in this example, the strongest hand will have rank 5 and its bid
> will be multiplied by 5.
>
> So, the first step is to put the hands in order of strength:
>
> - 32T3K is the only one pair and the other hands are all a stronger type, so it gets rank 1.
> - KK677 and KTJJT are both two pair. Their first cards both have the same label, but the second card of KK677 is stronger (K vs T), so
>   KTJJT gets rank 2 and KK677 gets rank 3.
> - T55J5 and QQQJA are both three of a kind. QQQJA has a stronger first card, so it gets rank 5 and T55J5 gets rank 4.
>
> Now, you can determine the total winnings of this set of hands by
> adding up the result of multiplying each hand's bid with its rank (765
>
> - 1 + 220 * 2 + 28 * 3 + 684 * 4 + 483 * 5). So the total winnings in this example are 6440.
>
> Find the rank of every hand in your set. What are the total winnings?

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#
# Solver for https://adventofcode.com/2023/day/7 part 1
# Redirect the input file to this script, for example day7part1.sh < path/to/input.txt
#

set -euo pipefail

is_high() { [ $# = 5 ]; }

is_one_pair() { [ $# = 4 ]; }

is_two_pair() {
  [ $# = 3 ] || return
  for count; do
    ((count != 3)) || return 1
  done
}

is_three_of_a_kind() {
  [ $# = 3 ] || return
  for count; do
    ((count == 3)) && return
  done
  return 1
}

is_full_house() {
  [ $# = 2 ] || return
  (($1 == 3 || $2 == 3))
}

is_four_of_a_kind() {
  [ $# = 2 ] || return
  (($1 == 4 || $2 == 4))
}

is_five_of_a_kind() { [ $# = 1 ]; }

solve_2023_day7_part1() {
  local strengths=(
    is_high
    is_one_pair
    is_two_pair
    is_three_of_a_kind
    is_full_house
    is_four_of_a_kind
    is_five_of_a_kind
  )

  local -A card_counts
  local hand bid strength i c fun
  while read -r hand bid; do
    card_counts=()
    for ((i = 0; i < ${#hand}; ++i)); do
      c=${hand:i:1}
      ((card_counts[$c] = ${card_counts[$c]:-0} + 1))
    done

    strength=0
    for fun in "${strengths[@]}"; do
      # Disable warning, the values are internal and safe.
      # shellcheck disable=SC2206
      "$fun" "${card_counts[@]}" && break
      ((++strength))
    done
    echo "$strength $hand $bid"
  done |
    tr TJQKA abcde |
    sort |
    awk '{ sum += NR * $3 } END { print sum }'
}

solve_2023_day7_part1
```

#### Part 2

> To make things a little more interesting, the Elf introduces one
> additional rule. Now, J cards are jokers - wildcards that can act like
> whatever card would make the hand the strongest type possible.
>
> To balance this, J cards are now the weakest individual cards, weaker
> even than 2. The other cards stay in the same order: A, K, Q, T, 9, 8,
> 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, J.
>
> J cards can pretend to be whatever card is best for the purpose of
> determining hand type; for example, QJJQ2 is now considered four of a
> kind. However, for the purpose of breaking ties between two hands of
> the same type, J is always treated as J, not the card it's pretending
> to be: JKKK2 is weaker than QQQQ2 because J is weaker than Q.
>
> Now, the above example goes very differently:
>
> > ```
> > 32T3K 765
> > T55J5 684
> > KK677 28
> > KTJJT 220
> > QQQJA 483
> > ```
>
> - 32T3K is still the only one pair; it doesn't contain any jokers, so its strength doesn't increase.
> - KK677 is now the only two pair, making it the second-weakest hand.
> - T55J5, KTJJT, and QQQJA are now all four of a kind! T55J5 gets rank 3, QQQJA gets rank 4, and KTJJT gets rank 5.
>
> With the new joker rule, the total winnings in this example are 5905.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#
# Solver for https://adventofcode.com/2023/day/7 part 2
# Redirect the input file to this script, for example day7part2.sh < path/to/input.txt
#

set -euo pipefail

__HIGH_CARD=1
__ONE_PAIR=2
__TWO_PAIR=3
__THREE_OF_A_KIND=4
__FULL_HOUSE=5
__FOUR_OF_A_KIND=6
__FIVE_OF_A_KIND=7

global_strength=0

is_high() {
  [ $# = 5 ] && global_strength=$__HIGH_CARD
}

is_one_pair() {
  [ $# = 4 ] && global_strength=$__ONE_PAIR
}

is_two_pair() {
  [ $# = 3 ] || return
  for count; do
    ((count != 3)) || return
  done
  global_strength=$__TWO_PAIR
}

is_three_of_a_kind() {
  [ $# = 3 ] || return
  for count; do
    ((count == 3)) && global_strength=$__THREE_OF_A_KIND && return
  done
  return 1
}

is_full_house() {
  [ $# = 2 ] || return
  (($1 == 3 || $2 == 3)) && global_strength=$__FULL_HOUSE
}

is_four_of_a_kind() {
  [ $# = 2 ] || return
  (($1 == 4 || $2 == 4)) && global_strength=$__FOUR_OF_A_KIND
}

is_five_of_a_kind() {
  [ $# = 1 ] && global_strength=$__FIVE_OF_A_KIND
}

strengths=(
  is_high
  is_one_pair
  is_two_pair
  is_three_of_a_kind
  is_full_house
  is_four_of_a_kind
  is_five_of_a_kind
)

# Computes stregth of a hand and stores in the global variable $global_strength.
compute_strength() {
  local hand=$1 i c
  local -A card_counts

  for ((i = 0; i < ${#hand}; ++i)); do
    c=${hand:i:1}
    ((card_counts[$c] = ${card_counts[$c]:-0} + 1))
  done

  for fun in "${strengths[@]}"; do
    # Disable warning, the values are internal and safe.
    # shellcheck disable=SC2206
    "$fun" "${card_counts[@]}" && return
  done
}

illegal_hand_and_strength() {
  local hand=$1
  local strength=$2
  echo >&2 "Illegal state: hand=$hand strength=$strength"
  exit 1
}

solve_2023_day7_part2() {
  local hand bid strength rest
  while read -r hand bid; do
    compute_strength "$hand"
    strength=$global_strength
    if [[ $hand =~ J ]]; then
      case ${hand//[^J]} in
        JJJJ*) strength=$__FIVE_OF_A_KIND ;;
        JJJ)
          rest=${hand//J}
          if [ "${rest:0:1}" = "${rest:1:1}" ]; then
            strength=$__FIVE_OF_A_KIND
          else
            strength=$__FOUR_OF_A_KIND
          fi
          ;;
        JJ)
          case $strength in
            "$__ONE_PAIR") strength=$__THREE_OF_A_KIND ;;
            "$__TWO_PAIR") strength=$__FOUR_OF_A_KIND ;;
            "$__FULL_HOUSE") strength=$__FIVE_OF_A_KIND ;;
            *) illegal_hand_and_strength "$hand" "$strength" ;;
          esac
          ;;
        J)
          case $strength in
            "$__HIGH_CARD") strength=$__ONE_PAIR ;;
            "$__ONE_PAIR") strength=$__THREE_OF_A_KIND ;;
            "$__TWO_PAIR") strength=$__FULL_HOUSE ;;
            "$__THREE_OF_A_KIND") strength=$__FOUR_OF_A_KIND ;;
            "$__FOUR_OF_A_KIND") strength=$__FIVE_OF_A_KIND ;;
            *) illegal_hand_and_strength "$hand" "$strength" ;;
          esac
          ;;
        *) illegal_hand_and_strength "$hand" "$strength" ;;
      esac
    fi
    echo "$strength ${hand//J/0} $bid"
  done |
    tr TQKA acde |
    sort |
    awk '{ sum += NR * $3 } END { print sum }'
}

solve_2023_day7_part2
```

#### Review request

I know this is a bit whimsical, and Bash is a poor choice to solve algorithmic puzzles. Also, this code is intended as a one-off, and not for reuse. I'm solving in Bash because, and as long as, it gives me joy. My main goals are:

- Compute the correct solution to the full input within seconds.
- Use idiomatic Bash.
- Easy to read and understand.

Do you see any patterns here that you would replace with better patterns?

Do you see a simpler way to solve any part of the puzzle with Bash and common shell tools?

What would you do differently?